# Failing to replicate the Chapter 6 example of "Terraform Up and Running" source in .tfvars file

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to replicate the model described in "Terraform Up and Running" chapter 6, where a repository contains the modules (.tf files), and another contains just .tfvars files that refer to the modules with a source argument.

This code put in terraform.tfvars does not work, module is not fetched, terrafrom reports no changes (nothing to apply).

```
source = "github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc.git?ref=v1.64.0"

name = "simple-example"

cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

azs             = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b", "eu-west-1c"]
private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24", "10.0.103.0/24"]

assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = true
enable_nat_gateway = true
single_nat_gateway = true

public_subnet_tags = {
  Name = "overridden-name-public"
}

tags = {
  Owner       = "user"
  Environment = "dev"
}

vpc_tags = {
  Name = "vpc-name"
}
```

When I paste the same in a .tf file within a "module" statement, it works, terraform init will fetch the module, and apply will create resources. But when I put it simply in a .tfvars file as suggested in the book, it won't fetch the module, and will not create any resources.

Wondering if I'm misunderstanding the example in the book. I find the idea of having modules in one location, and variables in another, very elegant, but I struggle making it work.

Comment: Can you show the full code here?

Comment: I added the full code. Note that I may be misunderstanding the Terraform Up and Running book. Reading the end of chapter 6 seems to suggest that a .tfvars file with the source of a component is sufficient to provision resources.

Comment: What you've posted is not currently valid Terraform code. Is it meant to be a module that you've dropped the module definition line from the top and the closing brace from?

Comment: It's supposed to be a terraform.tfvars file, not a .tf file. The "Terraform Up and Running" book shows a way of working with just .tfvars files. The file has a source = "..." statement at the top that references the module (another git repo). The format is the one for .tfvars files, not a regular module. If I surround it with module statement it works. But I finded the .tfvars option leaner and was trying to make it work. If it does not I'll just revert to good old modules.

Comment: It's not currently valid. If you variablised literally all of the module definition then sure but at that point it's basically pointless.

Comment: That would be the point, put everything in modules, and use the modules with just a configuration file. If it's not valid I'll use .tf files. Thanks for your help.